# How to perform multiple filter

Tags: sql, oracle

So here's a presentation of the problem.
2 tables:

- worker: worker_join_id, birth_date
- client: client_join_id, worker_join_id, buy_date, client_action

And I'd like to select all workers and the last client associate to the worker with a condition on client_action, and also the last buy_date of said client. And add all sort of information from other tables (not much relevant in the problem)

So one way to select the worker_join_id with my conditions is

```
select  w.worker_join_id, max(c.buy_date)
  from client c    
    join worker w
      on w.worker_join_id = c.worker_join_id
  where c.client_action IN ('BuyItem1', ''BuyItem2', ''BuyItem4')
  group by w.worker_join_id;
```

This selection give me access to the specific workers that I was looking for, with also the date i was interrested in.
But to add information from the client table and other tables i need to do more join. So i want to put this request in a "with"

```
with MyTable (worker_join_id, buy_date) as (
  select  w.worker_join_id, max(c.buy_date)
  from client c    
    join worker w
      on w.worker_join_id = c.worker_join_id
  where c.client_action IN ('BuyItem1', ''BuyItem2', ''BuyItem4')
  group by w.worker_join_id)
```

And then made my select with a join on MyTable to filter what i want:

```
select {lots of things} 
from worker w 
inner join client c 
      on w.w.worker_join_id = c.worker_join_id 
      and c.buy_date = (select t.buy_date from MyTable t 
                       join client c_tmp  
                        on t.worker_join_id = c_tmp.worker_join_id)
```

The stronger in sql of you may have notice the issue, but my sub-request give too many row. In my mind I wanted "c_tmp.worker_join_id" and "c.worker_join_id" to be the same thing, so i'll get what i want, but it's not.

So maybe I'll need to completely change my way arround the problem but I'm kinda block right now.

I'll wait for the communitee feedback, if you guys have solutions for my issue.
Thanks.

Comment: I'm on an oracle database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you can put references to a table outside of a subquery, within a subquery.

So in my case I can keep the query 'architecture' and just make my query like this

```
select {lots of things} 
from worker w 
inner join client c 
  on w.w.worker_join_id = c.worker_join_id 
  and c.buy_date = (select t.buy_date from MyTable t 
                    WHERE t.worker_join_id = c.worker_join_id)
```

The use of a reference on client table allow me to specify the subquery, so it gives me only the matching result

Answer (score 0):

This is only an illustration, Run subquery first and check please

```
select {lots of things} 
from worker w 
       inner join client c 
      on w.worker_join_id = c.worker_join_id 
      and c.buy_date =  (select max(c.buy_date) buy_date from client c   join worker w
                          join client c_tmp  on w.worker_join_id = c.worker_join_id
                          where c.client_action IN ('BuyItem1', 'BuyItem2', 'BuyItem4') )
```

Comment: I'll try that tomorrow (i assume you forget to remove "buy_date" and "join client c_tmp" in the subquery)

Comment: No, i doesn't work, the subrequest only give the latest date where a client buy something. And i end up with also only one worker.
Or the purpose was to select every worker, with a special buy date associated to them

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at window functions:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/last-value-transact-sql

So you want the last client for a worker, right?

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    stuff,
    last_value(c.client_join_id) OVER (PARTITION BY c.worker_join_id ORDER BY c.buy_date RANGE BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS last_client_join_id
FROM worker w
JOIN client c USING (worker_join_id)
WHERE c.client_action IN ('BuyItem1', 'BuyItem2', 'BuyItem4')
```

just as an example.
`PARTITION` works like `GROUP BY` without applying the grouping to the result set. So `last_value` takes the last value from every group, ordered by buy_date.

`DISTINCT` is necessary, because, as I stated earlier, this does not apply any grouping, so you'll have dupplicates.

Comment: I'm actually looking for the last client of a worker THAT has executed specific action. 
Never use partition before, i'll check in W3C doc what it does

Comment: Don't check W3C doc. W3C is for web technologies. SQL is not a W3C thing.
As far as I know, very few database engines support this feature, and 2 of them being PostgreSQL (and, therefore, Amazon RedShift) and Microsoft SQL Server, which is what you're probably using. They use a slightly different syntax though.

Consult the documentation of the RDBMS that you're using.

The window functions allow you to look ahead or behind on subsets of data, or rank it somehow or whatever. In this case, it's getting the last value of subsets of data.